# Difference in European / Ridgemont SPO connection from Powershell?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I'm using a Powershell script to upload files to SPO and everything pretty much works fine when DNS is returning Redmond ip, files get uploaded and no errors thrown.

When DNS however returns the European (Amsterdam) ip it stops working.

The SPO url gets resolves to two ip's:

**40.108.195.25** - Microsoft EU/Netherlands (NL)
**13.107.136.9** - Microsoft US/Redmond (US)

This snippet works when SPO hostname gets resolved to Redmond (**13.107.136.9**):

```
    $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($url)
    $Ctx.Credentials = $Credentials
    $Web = $Ctx.Web
    $Ctx.Load($Web)
    $TargetFolder = $Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl($targetlocation)
    $Ctx.Load($TargetFolder)
    $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

When DNS returns the EU/Netherlands ip (**40.108.195.25**) it fails with:

```
 Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send."
```

I looked a bit deeper but I can only spot differences using cURL:

**13.107.136.9** (the working one):

```
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
.....
```

**40.108.195.25** (the connection resetting one):

```
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
```

For now I hardcoded **13.107.136.9** in the host file but that is obviously not a preferred solution but I can't understand why it is happening.

Does anyone have any idea what could be the issue?

Thx!

*For completeness sake, the whole script:*

```
# Incoming parameters
param (
    [string]$url,
    [string]$username,
    [string]$password,
    [string]$filename,
    [string]$targetlocation
)


Write-Host ""
Write-Host "url: $url"
Write-Host "username: $username"
Write-Host "filename: $filename"
Write-Host "targetlocation: $targetlocation"
Write-Host ""

#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

#Setup Credentials to connect
$Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username,(ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force))


Try {
    #Setup the context
    $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($url)
    $Ctx.Credentials = $Credentials
    #Get the Target Folder to upload
    $Web = $Ctx.Web
    $Ctx.Load($Web)
    $TargetFolder = $Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl($targetlocation)
    $Ctx.Load($TargetFolder)
    $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

    #Get the source file from disk
    $FileStream = ([System.IO.FileInfo] (Get-Item $filename)).OpenRead()
    #Get File Name from source file path
    $SourceFileName = Split-path $filename -leaf
    $TargetFileURL = $targetlocation+"/"+$SourceFileName


    #Upload the File to SharePoint Library Folder
    $FileCreationInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileCreationInformation
    $FileCreationInfo.Overwrite = $true
    $FileCreationInfo.ContentStream = $FileStream
    $FileCreationInfo.URL = $TargetFileURL
    $FileUploaded = $TargetFolder.Files.Add($FileCreationInfo)
    $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

    #Close file stream
    $FileStream.Close()
    Write-host "File '$TargetFileURL' Uploaded Successfully!" -ForegroundColor Green

}
catch {
    write-host "Error Uploading File to Folder: $($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor Red
}
```

EDIT:
To exclude possible firewall issues I've done the same test from a complete other network and get the same outcome.

Answer (score 0):

The `13.107.136.9 - Microsoft US/Redmond (US)` IP also stopped working after a few weeks forcing me to analyse this in-depth since for no apparent reason it just "stopped working".

After many hours of pulling my hair out and a large amount of expletives it turned out I needed to add this to make it work:

`[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 'TLS11','TLS12','ssl3'`